# JAXB: marshalling objects with attributes gives a xml with namespaces redeclared

Tags: jaxb, marshalling, xml-namespaces

I have this xml:

```
<tag1 xmlns="myNamespace.com/#">
    <insideTag myAttribute="5">
        some text
    </insideTag>
</tag1>
```

but after marshalling it becomes this:

```
<tag1 xmlns="myNamespace.com">
    <insideTag xmlns:ns1="myNamespace.com/#" xmlns="" myAttribute="5">
        some text
    </insideTag>
</tag1>
```

I know, its almost the same but i really need that xml be like the first one.

I have no xsd to this xml. Actually, that xml is parsed to become a org.w3c.dom.Element, added in a ObjectType (xsd and class simplified implementations below) then this ObjectType is marshalled.
And if this matters, I am using a NamespacePrefixMapper.
xsd (note that attributeFormDefault is unset)

```
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="0.1"
  xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <complexType name="ObjectType" mixed="true">
        <sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "ObjectType", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#",
   propOrder = { "content" })
public class ObjectType{
    @XmlMixed
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> content;

    public List<Object> getContent() {
        if (content == null) {
            content = new ArrayList<Object>();
        }
        return this.content;
    }
}
```

So... someone know how to solve this?
By the way...the solution has to work with jaxb-impl-2.1.4 too.

Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid unnecessary namespase, you need to register in `ObjectFactory` class like this:

```
@XmlElementDecl(name="CurrencyPayTypeCode") 
public JAXBElement<OLILUMEASUNITS> createCurrencyPayTypeCode(OLILUMEASUNITS elem) {
                return new JAXBElement<OLILUMEASUNITS>(new QName("OLILUMEASUNITS"), OLILUMEASUNITS.class, elem); 
}
```

Where:

1. `CurrencyPayTypeCode` - name of insideTag
2. `OLILUMEASUNITS` - A class that can this tag unmarshalling